# Keep on regenerating a new id and checking the data base till the condition is met?

Tags: php

I have this script that creates a unique applicant id for a form application and if the user is ever in a situation were their generated id already exist in the

database, I want the if condition to keep on running and checking the database till there is not a match id in the database so that user can obtain a unique id

for them self. How would I do something like that? I want them to eventually move on to the else condition if a unique id has been generated?

I'm stuck how I can do this. This is my code

```
<?php

/*<Generate a unique applicant id>*/

$applicant_id_characters= '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-_';
$applicant_generation_id = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < 11; $i++){
    $applicant_generation_id .= $applicant_id_characters[mt_rand(0, 63)];
}

/*</Generate a unique applicant id>*/

/*<Check if a unique applicant id exist or not. Response>*/

$db_servername= 'localhost';
$db_username= 'jd';
$db_password= '1234';
$db_name='example_1234';

$db_connect= new mysqli($db_servername,$db_username,$db_password,$db_name);

$db_query= "SELECT*FROM applications WHERE applicant_id= '$applicant_generation_id'";

$db_result= $db_connect->query($db_query);

if($db_result->num_rows = 1){
    /*Keep on regenerating a unique id till there is not a match 
    in the database and then move onto the else condition. How???*/

    $applicant_id_characters= '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-_';
    $applicant_generation_id = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < 11; $i++){
        $applicant_generation_id .= $applicant_id_characters[mt_rand(0, 63)];
    }
  //??
} else{
    $applicant_id= $applicant_generation_id;
}

/*</Check if a unique applicant id exist or not. Response>*/

echo "You’re unique id is ".$applicant_id;

?>
```

Comment: Use a `while` loop and regenerate the ID until it's unique in the database. Or use GUIDs where collisions are very unlikely.

Comment: Can you give a code example of the structure of my example?

Comment: If you don't know how that's ok.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on sticky bit's comment.

You need to use a loop instead of a conditional to keep checking. In your example, replace your `if` with a `while`

```
while($db_result->num_rows = 1){

    $applicant_id_characters= '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-_';
    $applicant_generation_id = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < 11; $i++){
        $applicant_generation_id .= $applicant_id_characters[mt_rand(0, 63)];
    }

    $db_query= "SELECT*FROM applications WHERE applicant_id= '$applicant_generation_id'";

    $db_result= $db_connect->query($db_query);
}
```

Better yet would be to use a do...while to eliminate the duplicate code, but I'll leave that up to you.